# How to detect program termination in C/Linux?

Tags: c, linux, process

How can an application find out that it just started terminating ? Can I use signal handler for that ?

Comment: yes, unless it's terminated by the KILL signal. Take a look at "signal" in the manual (`man signal`)

Comment: You should use `sigaction` instead as it is more portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable [`atexit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit). It will call a function when program terminated normally.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>    
void funcall(void);
void fnExit1 (void)
{
  printf ("Exit function \n");
}

int main ()
{
  atexit (fnExit1);
  printf ("Main function start\n");
  funcall();
  printf ("Main function end\n");
  return 0;
}

void funcall(void)
{
    sleep(2);
    exit(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Main function start
Exit function
```

Comment: The atexit() runs after all threads in the application is terminated ?

Answer (score 0):

You Could try `--->` `int raise (int sig)`

And handle when `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL` is raised!!

Comment: I want to catch self termination (not only upon request from another process) . For example, by Ctrl+\, Ctr+C, or assert, crash etc. So SIGTERM and SIGKILL are not the only signals that need to be handled. I need a single place where I can handle all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also register a function to be called upon exit of a process. See `man atexit`

Answer (score 0):

You can install a signal handler for SIGINT ,SIGKILL and SIGSEGV. In the signal handler you can take a stack dump so you can debug your application later.In the signal handler set the disposition of SIGINT ,SIGKILL and SIGSEGV back to default.